# Why does the exception keep fluctuating and moving to new areas? The stack trace does not answer questions

Tags: java, database, exception, syntax

I am writing a Java program to create, write to, edit, delete an instance for a derby database for a college assignment. I have corrected all other errors but am throwing the SQL exception `SQL State:  42Y07`

```
----- SQLException -----
SQL State:  42Y07
Error Code: 20000
Message:    Schema 'USER1' does not exist
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'USER1' does not exist
```

I am new to SQL and cannot see where the error is. This is my SQL file:

```
package animaljdbc;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DataBase {    
private static DataBase DATABASE_INSTANCE = new DataBase();                 // Singleton
private DataBase() {}                                                       // a private constructor so no callers can instantiate the singleton object directly
public static synchronized DataBase getInstance() {                         // a public static method for callers to get a reference to the singleton instance
    return DATABASE_INSTANCE;
}
Utility utils = Utility.getInstance();                                      // Create a new Utilities
private final String dbName = "AnimalsDB";                                  
private final String tableName = "Animals";                             // Name of the table
private final String framework = "embedded";
private final String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
private final String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
private final String Table = "create table " + tableName + " (id int, type varchar(32), color varchar(32), gender varchar(32)," 
                 + " isVertebrate String, canSwim String)";
Connection conn = null;
private final ArrayList statements = new ArrayList();                   // List of Statements, PreparedStatements, flushed after every method run
PreparedStatement psInsert = null;
PreparedStatement psUpdate = null;
Statement s = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Properties props = new Properties();                                        // connection properties


public void loadDBdriver() {                                                // Loads the appropriate JDBC driver for this environment/framework. For        
    try {                                                                   // example, if we are in an embedded environment, we load Derby's
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();                                // embedded Driver, <code>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</code>. 
        System.out.println("Loaded the appropriate driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println("\nUnable to load the JDBC driver " + driver);
        System.err.println("Please check your CLASSPATH.");
        cnfe.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (InstantiationException ie) {
        System.err.println(
                    "\nUnable to instantiate the JDBC driver " + driver);
        ie.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        System.err.println(
                    "\nNot allowed to access the JDBC driver " + driver);
        iae.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

protected void createDB() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    System.out.println("Database in " + framework + " mode");
    loadDBdriver();                                                         // Load the desired JDBC driver        
    try {                                                                   // load JDBC
        props.put("user", "user1");                                         // providing a user name and password is optional in the embedded   
        props.put("password", "user1");   
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName + ";create=true", props);  // Setup the connection to the database
        System.out.println("Database" + dbName + "created and connected ");
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);                                          // We want to control transactions manually. Autocommit is on by default in JDBC.            
        s = conn.createStatement();                                         // Creating a statement object that we can use for running various SQL statements commands against the database.
        statements.add(s);
        s.execute(Table);                                                   // We create a table...
        System.out.println("Created table " + tableName);
        statements.clear();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    }
}

//@param e the SQLException from which to print details.
public static void printSQLException(SQLException e) {                      // Prints details of an SQLException chain to <code>System.err</code>.
    while (e != null)                                                       // Details included are SQL State, Error code, Exception message.
    {                                                                       // Unwraps the entire exception chain to unveil the real cause of the Exception.
        System.err.println("\n----- SQLException -----");
        System.err.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
        System.err.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
        System.err.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        e = e.getNextException();
    }
}     

 /**
 * @param type
 * @param color
 * @param gender
 * @param isVertebrate
 * @param canSwim
 * @return
 */
public boolean insertObject(String type, String color, String gender, String isVertebrate, String canSwim) {             // This inserts a new animal into the database
    boolean condition = false;                                      // Return statement
    psInsert = null;

    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        psInsert = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (type, color, gender, isVertebrate, canSwim) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        statements.add(psInsert);                                       // Prepare for insert()
        psInsert.setString(1, type);                                    // Insert the input
        psInsert.setString(2, color);
        psInsert.setString(3, gender);
            psInsert.setString(4, isVertebrate);
            psInsert.setString(5, canSwim);
        psInsert.executeUpdate();                                       // Well....execute
        statements.clear();                                             // Clear statements
        condition = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    }           
    return condition;
}    

ArrayList<Utility> getAnimals() {
    ArrayList<Utility> animalium = new ArrayList<>();                       // To hold the animals we want to return
    rs = null;
    try {                                                                   
        rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " ORDER BY type"); 
        while (rs.next()) {                                                 // temp animal to push to the arraylist                
            Utility temporaryAnimalium = new Utility(rs.getInt(1),          // ID
                                                     rs.getString(2),   // Type
                                                     rs.getString(3),   // Color
                                                     rs.getString(4),   // Gender
                                                     rs.getString(5),       // is Vertebrate
                                                     rs.getString(6));      // canSwim 
            animalium.add(temporaryAnimalium);                              // Add to the arraylist
        }
        try {                                                               // Release resources
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            printSQLException(sqle);
        }
        statements.clear();                                                 // Clear statements
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    } 
    return animalium;                                                       // Return our animal list
}

 /**
 * @return
 */
public boolean closeDB() {                                                  // Closes out the connection to the database and clears statements
    boolean condition = false;                                      // Return statements
    statements.clear();                                                     // Clear statements
    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        s.execute("DROP TABLE " + tableName);                               // Drop the table
        conn.commit();                                                      // We commit the transaction. Any changes will be persisted to the database now.  

        if (framework.equals("embedded")) {
            try {
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");   // the shutdown=true attribute shuts down Derby
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                if (((se.getErrorCode() == 50000) && ("XJ015".equals(se.getSQLState())))) {
                    System.out.println("Database shut down normally");      // we got the expected exception
                } else {                      
                    System.err.println("Database did not shut down normally");  // if the error code or SQLState is different, we have an unexpected exception (shutdown failed)
                    printSQLException(se);
                }
            }
        }condition = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    } finally {
        int i = 0;                                                          // release all open resources to avoid unnecessary memory usage
        while (!statements.isEmpty()) {                                     // Statements and PreparedStatements
            Statement st = (Statement)statements.remove(i);                 // PreparedStatement extend Statement
            try {
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                    st = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                printSQLException(sqle);
            }
        }
        try {                                                               //Connection
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            printSQLException(sqle);
        }
    }       
    return condition;
}

public boolean updateDB(int id, String type, String color, String gender, String isVertebrate, String canSwim) {
    boolean condition = false;                                      // Return statement
    psUpdate = null;
    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        psUpdate = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET type=?, color=?, gender=?, isVertebrate=?, canSwim=? WHERE id=?");
        statements.add(psUpdate);                                   // Prepare the statement for insertion of values
        psUpdate.setString(1, type);                                    // Update and set integers and strings, inserting the values
        psUpdate.setString(2, color);
        psUpdate.setString(3, gender);
        psUpdate.setString(4, isVertebrate);
            psUpdate.setString(5, canSwim);
            psUpdate.setInt(6, id);
        psUpdate.executeUpdate();                                       // Well....execute 
        statements.clear();                                             // Clear statements   
        condition = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle); }          
    return condition;
}

/**
 * @param message
 */
public void reportFailure(String message) {                                 // Reports a data verification failure to System.err with the given message.
    System.err.println("\nData could not be verified: ");
    System.err.println('\t' + message);
}

public boolean delete(int id) {
    boolean state = false;                                                  // Return statement
    psUpdate = null;
    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        psUpdate = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE id=?");  // Statement preparation
        statements.add(psUpdate);
        psUpdate.setInt(1, id);                                         // ID we wish to delete
        psUpdate.executeUpdate();                                       // Well....execute 
        statements.clear();                                             // Clear statements   
        state = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    }

    return state;
}

// method to close the dB connection
protected void finishDB(){                                                  // method to close the dB connection
    if (framework.equals("embedded"))
    {
        try
        {
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");       // the shutdown=true attribute shuts down Derby
        }                                                                   // To shut down a specific database only, but keep the
        catch (SQLException se)                                             // engine running (for example for connecting to other
        {                                                                   // databases), specify a database in the connection URL:
            if (( (se.getErrorCode() == 50000)                              //DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";shutdown=true");
                    && ("XJ015".equals(se.getSQLState()) ))) {
                System.out.println("Derby shut down normally");             // we got the expected exception
                System.out.println();                                       // Note that for single database shutdown, the expected
            } else {                                                        // SQL state is "08006", and the error code is 45000.
                System.err.println("Derby did not shut down normally");     // if the error code or SQLState is different, we have
                System.out.println();                                       // an unexpected exception (shutdown failed)
                printSQLException(se);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the printed stack trace:

```
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at animaljdbc.DataBase.createDB(DataBase.java:74)
at animaljdbc.AnimalJDBC.main(AnimalJDBC.java:29)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Schema 'USER1' does not exist
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 10 more
Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'USER1' does not exist
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.bindUserType(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ColumnDefinitionNode.checkUserType(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.TableElementList.validate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CreateTableNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
```

How do I read the stack trace? The error is suposedly in line 74 but the schema user1 is in line 67 or 68. How do I fix it?

Comment: "This is my SQL file" - no that's Java source with a few SQL statements in it. Besides that your error hints at malformed SQL so you need to check your statements (debug your application and check the generated strings). Refer to the lines stated in the stacktrace to start your debugging process, e.g. `DataBase line 74` (whichever line that is).

Comment: The exception you complain about and the stacktrace you post suggest completely different errors. Trace and debug your statements carefully.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: I would like the program to run completely and allow users to add animals to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to me you do not have a table named USER1, try creating one and running again, that should fix this.

Comment: At lines 67 and 68 the program sets the username and password to user1. I thought that the table was supposed to be named Animalium

Comment: I am researching the issue but it lies in the username and password being set. This is code supplied by the teacher so I don't understand what the problem is. How do I correctly set the username and password?

Comment: I suggest you to create the table USER1 with its properties then check if the program runs correctly, if it is than somethings wrong with the CREATION of the table, if it's not than the problem can be in connection, Username and Password for the db or the properties that you try to assign.

Comment: I set tableName to USER1 and it still would not run

Answer (score 0):

The critical place to look is the **Caused By** section(s) of the stack trace.

> Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: **Encountered "(" at line 1, column 99.**

So print out the SQL you are generating before you run the query and see what the problem is. You clearly have an issue with the query.

Also notice:

> at animaljdbc.DataBase.createDB(DataBase.java:74)

so it is in your `createDB` method.